# How to return a message from PHP page to AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an index.html file that contains a form, I have one PHP file that just checks an email,
here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
if($email=="abc@gmail.com")
{
echo "email is ok";
}
else
 {
echo "email is not ok";
}
?>
```

I want if the email is OK then it should do nothing but if email is not OK then it should print something on the panel.
Here is the Ajax and jQuery code

```
  $.ajax({
    url : "register_user.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : formData,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
   success: function(data)
   {
       if(data=="Success")
       {
        //if email is OK
       }
       else
        {
          //if email is not OK
          $('#panel').show();
          $('#error_message').html(data);
        }
   }

  });
```

Comment: So what is the specific problem or error with the code shown and what is the question?

Comment: Can you tell us what the data returns ?

Comment: You are returning `email is ok` or `email is not ok` as response but comparing it with `data=="Success"` ?

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string` there? Remove that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use json as a response in php file and then parse json in ajax call .
something like

```
<?php

include "connection.php";
$email = $_POST['email'];
if ($email === "abc@gmail.com") {
    echo json_encode(["result" => "email is ok"]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(["result" => "email is not ok"]);
}
```

```
$.ajax({
  url: "register_user.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(json_data);

    if (response.result === "email is not ok") {
      $("#panel").show();
      $("#error_message").html(response.result);
    }
  },
});
```